# Manipulate Python Data frame to plot line charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have the following data frame:

Parameters Year 2016 Year 2017 Year 2018....

0)   X           10          12      13

1)    Y           12          12      45

2)    Z           89          23      97

3
.
.
.

I want to make a line chart with the column headers starting from Year 2016 to be on the x-axis and each line on the chart to represent each of the parameters - X, Y, Z

I am using the matplotlib library to make the plot but it is throwing errors.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace with the error that is being thrown? Also, the code you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parameters':['X','Y','Z'],
                  'Year 2016':[10,12,13],
                  'Year 2017':[12,12,45],
                  'Year 2018':[89,23,97]})
```

Input Dataframe:

```
  Parameters  Year 2016  Year 2017  Year 2018
0          X         10         12         89
1          Y         12         12         23
2          Z         13         45         97
```

You can use some dataframe shaping and pandas plot:

```
df_out  = df.set_index('Parameters').T
df_out.set_axis(pd.to_datetime(df_out.index, format='Year %Y'), axis=0, inplace=False)\
      .plot()
```

Output Graph:

[image]

Comment: This works!!!! Thank you so much Scott! I am a complete newbie to Python entirely and I have been stuck on this since a day and has this deadline for a project submission. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pandas DataFrame, let's call it `df`, for which your columns are X, Y, Z, etc. and your rows are the years in order, you can simply call `df.plot()` to plot each column as a line with the y axis being the values and the row name giving the x-axis.

Comment: I am trying to do that using Transpose but after that I get the error: 
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

I think a transpose changes the datatype from numeric to object.

Comment: Hmm, would need to see your code and your data to be able to tell why that fails. It works with the example code given in Scott's answer.